# Cause: Broker: localhost - Client: tata_consumer already connected from tcp://127.0.0.1:52917

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jms-topic

I am new to ActiveMQ and trying to experiment working of topics. I have created a Producer using JMS and two Consumer listeners configured using Spring. I do know that if multiple consumers are used then every consumer should have a unique client id. Even after keeping the client id's unique, I get the same error.

```
ERROR | Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'hetal_rachh_topic' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=4, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Broker: localhost - Client: tata_consumer already connected from tcp://127.0.0.1:52917
ERROR | Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'hetal_rachh_topic' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=4, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Broker: localhost - Client: cipla_consumer already connected from tcp://127.0.0.1:52918
```

**Note: I even tried creating just one JMS listener container and still the error says that the particular client is already connected.**

Steps of what I am trying to do -

1. Created a maven project with a REST controller having two API's. First API just initializes an arraylist. And second API calls a producer which sends message to topic using JMSTemplate.
2. Configured just one JMS listener in the spring context file
3. The UI code uses axios to make a call to the first API which initializes some arraylist. And then after every interval, calls the second API which calls producer to send messages which are further consumed by the listeners. The controller (second API) basically returns the JSON string of the messages received back to the UI.
4. I am not using any web server locally but tomcat7 plugin to run my spring project `mvn tomcat7:run`. I start a local AMQ server `activemq start` and start my UI code using `npm start`

Below is my ReactJs UI code snippet which makes axios calls.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.callCreateConnection();
    this.interval = setInterval(this.callStockUpdatesAPI, 15000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  async callCreateConnection() {
    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/stock-market-ticker/createConnection", {
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Response", res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
  }

  async callStockUpdatesAPI() {
    console.log("Inside api");
    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/stock-market-ticker/getStockUpdates", {
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Response", response.data);
        switch (response.data.symbol) {
          case "TATAMOTORS":
            let oldData_tata = { ...this.state.data };

            oldData_tata[0].price = response.data.price;
            oldData_tata[0].percent_change_1h = response.data.change_1hr;
            oldData_tata[0].percent_change_24h = response.data.change_24hr;
            this.setState({ data: oldData_tata });

            break;
          case "CIPLA":
            let oldData_cipla = { ...this.state.data };
            oldData_cipla[0].price = response.data.price;
            oldData_cipla[0].percent_change_1h = response.data.change_1hr;
            oldData_cipla[0].percent_change_24h = response.data.change_24hr;
            this.setState({ data: oldData_cipla });

            break;
          case "ASIANPAINT":
            let oldData_asian = { ...this.state.data };
            oldData_asian[1].price = response.data.price;
            oldData_asian[1].percent_change_1h = response.data.change_1hr;
            oldData_asian[1].percent_change_24h = response.data.change_24hr;
            this.setState({ data: oldData_asian });

            break;
          default:
            return;
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
 }
```

I have shared my Spring application code at https://github.com/hetalrachh/stock-market-ticker.

How can I fix this? If anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that each Spring `listener-container` is creating *multiple* listeners, and each of those multiple listeners is using the same `client-id` value from it's parent container. This is not allowed by the JMS specification. Try using `concurrency="1"` on your `listener-container` elements, e.g.:

```xml
    <jms:listener-container acknowledge="auto"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory" destination-type="durableTopic"
        client-id="tata_consumer" concurrency="1">
        <jms:listener destination="hetal_rachh_topic" ref="tataConsumer"
            method="onMessage" subscription="subscription" selector="symbol=TATAMOTORS" />
    </jms:listener-container>

    <jms:listener-container acknowledge="auto"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory" destination-type="durableTopic"
        client-id="cipla_consumer" concurrency="1">
        <jms:listener destination="hetal_rachh_topic" ref="ciplaConsumer"
            method="onMessage" subscription="subscription" selector="symbol=CIPLA" />
    </jms:listener-container>
```

Comment: I have created only one listener per container. Why would multiple listeners be created? @Justin Bertram

Comment: The error message you're receiving indicates otherwise. It's saying that both `tata_consumer` and  `cipla_consumer` are "already connected". Why would it say they were already connected if you only had one listener per container? Spring uses concurrent listeners for performance reasons so that multiple messages can be consumed at once. By setting `concurrency="1"` you're telling Spring *not* to create multiple listeners. Did you actually try this? If so, what was the result?

Comment: Just tried and I am still getting the same error. I will update my question to iterate what am I exactly trying to do. @Justin Bertram

Comment: I have updated my question with the steps @Justin Bertram

Comment: Unfortunately the update doesn't provide any further details on what the problem might be. Could you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which demonstrates the problem? Usually the this exercise itself uncovers the underlying problem, and if it doesn't then it allows others to reproduce the problem and investigate it for themselves rather than having to continue asking you questions for more details or providing potential solutions to try.

Comment: Okay. I will share my code on my github public repo and share the link soon @Justin Bertram

Comment: Keep in mind that there ideally needs to be an *automated* way to reproduce the problem. The more manual steps required to reproduce the problem the more tedious and error prone the process will be and the less likely it will be that you get a solution.

Comment: I believe just by running the Spring app you will be able to reproduce the problem when you run mvn tomcat7:run and start a local amq server. The error now occurs on tomcat start itself so the UI part is not required. I have updated my question according to my latest code. Let me know if anything else is required. @Justin Bertram

Comment: Just for the update, the issue is resolved. There was some issue with my tomcat folder which gets created in the project's target folder in the spring application. There might be some unclosed connection left in there due to which I was facing this issue. I deleted the tomcat folder, build the code again and it now works.